# How can I create a Google account without it being saved to my device?

Tags: sync, email, google

I want to create a Google account on my computer, but I don't want it saved to my device. For example, when I come on the place to log into my Google account, I don't want it to have my email address there, ready. I want to just type it in. Can I create a Google account without it being saved to my device?
A million thanks in advance,
Shay

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do that. You have to switch to incognito browsing on your browser.

Every browser has incognito. On Opera mini, it is called private browsing.

For Chrome, click on the three horizontal lines at the right-top side of the browser and select new incognito tab.

On Opera, you can switch to private browsing by clicking on the tabs icon then select Private.

I hope this helps.